# Basic Calculator in GUI

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make a Basic calculator with GUI. But I could not help it out.

The error is: `"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'IntVar' and 'str'"`

All the buttons work fine only the '=' gives a problem.

Please help with the idea that how to convert the `StringVar` to `IntVar`.
Here is my code:

```
import tkinter
window=tkinter.Tk()
def zero():
     x.set(x.get()+'0')
def one():
     x.set(x.get()+'1')
def two():
     x.set(x.get()+'2')
def three():
     x.set(x.get()+'3')
def four():
     x.set(x.get()+'4')
def five():
     x.set(x.get()+'5')
def six():
     x.set(x.get()+'6')
def seven():
     x.set(x.get()+'7')
def eight():
     x.set(x.get()+'8')
def nine():
     x.set(x.get()+'9')
def add():
     a=x.get()
     x.set('')
def ans():
     b=x.get()
     x.set(a+b)


frame=tkinter.Frame(window)
frame.pack()
x=tkinter.StringVar()
a=tkinter.IntVar()
b=tkinter.IntVar()

entry=tkinter.Entry(frame,textvariable=x)
entry.grid(row=0,column=0)
entry.pack

button0=tkinter.Button(frame,text='0',command=zero)
button0.grid(row=0,column=1)

button1=tkinter.Button(frame,text='1',command=one)
button1.grid(row=1,column=1)

button2=tkinter.Button(frame,text='2',command=two)
button2.grid(row=1,column=2)

button3=tkinter.Button(frame,text='3',command=three)
button3.grid(row=1,column=3)

button4=tkinter.Button(frame,text='4',command=four)
button4.grid(row=2,column=1)

button5=tkinter.Button(frame,text='5',command=five)
button5.grid(row=2,column=2)

button6=tkinter.Button(frame,text='6',command=six)
button6.grid(row=2,column=3)

button7=tkinter.Button(frame,text='7',command=seven)
button7.grid(row=3,column=1)

button8=tkinter.Button(frame,text='8',command=eight)
button8.grid(row=3,column=2)

button9=tkinter.Button(frame,text='9',command=nine)
button9.grid(row=3,column=3)

button9=tkinter.Button(frame,text='+',command=add)
button9.grid(row=0,column=2)

button10=tkinter.Button(frame,text='=',command=ans)
button10.grid(row=0,column=3)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: "The error" also says on what line it occurred. Please make sure to include all relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

In your `add` and `ans` functions, you use `a` and `b` as variables instead of `IntVar`s. Change them to:

```
def add():
     a.set(x.get())
     x.set('')
def ans():
     b.set(x.get())
     x.set(a.get()+b.get())
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using strings where you should use numbers(IntVar).

Use numbers

```
x=tkinter.IntVar()
a=tkinter.IntVar()
b=tkinter.IntVar()
```

try

```
x.set(x.get()+1)

[...]

def add():
     a=x.get()
     x.set(0)
def ans():
     b=x.get()
     x.set(a+b)
```

instead of

```
x.set(x.get()+'1')
```

Comment: if  i use the above idea i get this error  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/ishangrover/Desktop/Python Practice files/Basic Calculator.py", line 9, in two
    x.set(x.get()+'2')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: No, when you type `1` and `2` in a calculator (without pressing `+`), you expect it to become 12, not 3. That's why `x` is a string.

Comment: So what should make changes to get 12 rather than 3

Comment: @IshanGrover None, pressing `1` and `2` already gives 12 in the code you have. You should only make changes in the `add` and `ans` functions, as I've explained in my answer.